# Hadamard product with rank 1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization, estimation

Let $\odot$ represent Hadamard or pointwise multiplication. If $\pmb{Y}$ is a $\underline{given}$ positive definite square matrix, can i estimate a positive semi-definite $\pmb{X}$ matrix such that 
\begin{equation}
\pmb{Y} = \pmb{X} \odot \pmb{z}\pmb{z}^H
\end{equation} 
where $\pmb{z}$ is a complex vector with phases only (i.e. each element of $\pmb{z}$ is of magnitude $1$). Also $(.)^H$ stands for conjuate-transposition, or Hermitian (Thanks @igael). I really don't know where to start. Maybe, i have formulated a problem that does not make sense.

Comment: what is $\pmb{z}^H$ in your notation ? Hadamard product didn't need homogeneous elements ?

Comment: Hi @igael $\pmb{z}^H$ is conjugate-transposition.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by homogenous elements.

Comment: Let $m=(z_i^{-1})_{i=1}^n$. Notice that $Y \odot mm^H$ is a positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix by Schur theorem and $Y= (Y \odot mm^H)\odot zz^H$. Let $X=Y \odot mm^H$.

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbf Y = diag(\mathbf z)\mathbf X diag(\mathbf z^H)$. Since $diag(\mathbf z)diag(\mathbf z^H)=\mathbf I$, $\mathbf X$ can be estimated as $\mathbf X = diag(\mathbf z^H)\mathbf Y diag(\mathbf z)$, where $\mathbf z$ is any vector with your constraint.

Comment: Could you kindly explain how $diag(\pmb{z})diag(\pmb{z}^H) = \pmb{I}$.

Comment: each element of $\pmb{z}$ contains entries of magnitude $1$, but they are complex.

Comment: $\mathbf z=(exp(j\phi_1),\dots,exp(j\phi_n))$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh oh you are right, my bad. I thought you wrote $diag(\pmb{z}\pmb{z}^H)$. Again, my bad. Apoogies.

Comment: Next thing to note is the only given information is $\pmb{Y}$ and neither $\pmb{z}$ nor $\pmb{X}$.

Comment: Then probably something else should be known, otherwise, we can set $\mathbf X=\mathbf Y$ and $\mathbf z=(1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: Or just, take any $\mathbf z$ with your constraint and set $\mathbf X=$ as in my answer, i.e., there exist infinitely many solutions.